# Why are other universes in the picture of Dark Flow?

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics

It seems to me that the popular suggestive explanation of dark flow is another universe interacting with ours. Isn't there other alternative explanations?

Comment: I think 'dark flow' was discredited by the Planck satellite data. You can check wikipedia for more information.

Comment: @Danu: Promoters of Dark Flow [dispute the Planck Collaboration's analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.6614) of the data.